# Is Wi-Fi P2P ideal for a local chat-discovery app(Tinder similar)?

Tags: android, file, chat, wifi-direct, file-sharing

I wanted to know if WiFi P2P android API is ideal for use if we take lot of connections into consideration, tha app's users can be at time clients and servers they can share files and send messages and get them also as clients ? if no what is the best solution ( N.B : i'm opened to client/server architecture ).
I just wanted to know the limits of the API cited above and Thank you guys ...

Answer (score 0):

Wifi direct as a technology is ideal for peer to peer communication.However talking about wifi direct for android , it works well only for a single connection that is **only 1-1 use case** .It is possible to create a one to many where every device connects to the group owner (Soft AP).But even if u build a one to one and try extend to multi use case you will have problems with certain devices that do no connect perfectly.
Checkout some of the problems listed under problems after downloading this  application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.budius.WiFiShoot&hl=en

If you want to go for multiple connection it is better to use hotspot .One device ends up being the hotspot and other clients connect to the hotspot .It is being used by plenty of application like xender, zapiya.